# Identification of properties of a given FIR filter

Tags: finite-impulse-response, frequency-response, digital-filters, impulse-response, step-response

I have a FIR filter which is described via following transfer function

$$H(z) = h(0) + h(1)\cdot z^{-1} + h(1)\cdot z^{-2} + \ldots + h(23)\cdot z^{-23},$$
where the coefficients have below given values:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
h(0)  &=&  1.192308e-002 \\ 
h(1)  &=&  1.055184e-002 \\ 
h(2)  &=&  9.226209e-003 \\ 
h(3)  &=&  7.946184e-003 \\ 
h(4)  &=&  6.711766e-003 \\ 
h(5)  &=&  5.522955e-003 \\ 
h(6)  &=&  4.379751e-003 \\ 
h(7)  &=&  3.282153e-003 \\ 
h(8)  &=&  2.230161e-003 \\ 
h(9)  &=&  1.223776e-003 \\ 
h(10) &=&  2.629979e-004 \\ 
h(11) &=& -6.521739e-004 \\ 
h(12) &=& -1.521739e-003 \\ 
h(13) &=& -2.345698e-003 \\ 
h(14) &=& -3.12405e-003  \\ 
h(15) &=& -3.856795e-003 \\ 
h(16) &=& -4.543934e-003 \\ 
h(17) &=& -5.185467e-003 \\ 
h(18) &=& -5.781393e-003 \\ 
h(19) &=& -6.331712e-003 \\ 
h(20) &=& -6.836424e-003 \\ 
h(21) &=& -7.295531e-003 \\ 
h(22) &=& -7.70903e-003  \\ 
h(23) &=& -8.076923e-003
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The sampling period is $T_s = 100\,\mu\mathrm{s}$. I was curious what are the properties of this filter. Unfortunately I don't have the Matlab software so I have taken its free of charge counterpart called Scilab and I have written following script for examining the frequency response of the filter

```
// coefficients of the transfer function polynomial
B = [1.192308e-002, 1.055184e-002, 9.226209e-003, 7.946184e-003, 6.711766e-003, 5.522955e-003, 4.379751e-003, 3.282153e-003, 2.230161e-003, 1.223776e-003, 2.629979e-004, -6.521739e-004, -1.521739e-003, -2.345698e-003, -3.12405e-003, -3.856795e-003, -4.543934e-003, -5.185467e-003, -5.781393e-003, -6.331712e-003, -6.836424e-003, -7.295531e-003, -7.70903e-003, -8.076923e-003];

// transfer function in the z^-1
h_invz = poly(B, 'invz', 'c');

// relative frequencies - w*k*Ts = 2*pi*f/fs*k, maximum frequency is f = fs/2
// fr_max = f_max/fs = 0.5
fr = (0:0.0001:0.5);

// complex frequency response (transfer function in z^(-1))
// z = exp(s*T) = exp([sigma + j*omega]*T)
hf = freq(h_invz, 1, exp(-%i*2*%pi*fr));

// magnitude
magnitude = abs(hf);

// phase
hf_imag = imag(hf);
hf_real = real(hf);
phase = atan(hf_imag, hf_real);

scf();
plot(fr, magnitude);
title('Magnitude');
xlabel('$f_r = \frac{f}{f_s}$');
ylabel('$Mag(H(z))$');
xgrid;
scf();
plot(fr, phase);
title('Phase');
xlabel('$f_r = \frac{f}{f_s}$');
ylabel('$Arg(H(z))\,[\mathrm{rad}]$');
xgrid;
```

The output of my script is following

[image]

[image]

I have basically two questions:

1. Is the frequency response I have calculated with the Scilab correct?
2. What could be said about the filter properties?

**EDIT**:

I have extended my Scilab script and I have analyzed the time domain behavior. Namely I have evaluated the **impulse response** of the filter

[image]

and also the **step response** of the filter

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is the frequency response I have calculated with the Scilab correct?

Sort of. Your sample rate is 10kHz so your frequency axis should go from 0Hz to 5kHz. Other than that, it looks about right.

> What could be said about the filter properties?

Not a whole lot. It's a fairly odd filter. The impulse response looks like a truncated exponential decay with zero mean and large transients at both ends. So it's bit of mixture of a bandpass and a comb filter. It's not something I've seen before.